# How to list mysql databases by date created

Tags: mysql

I need to list my mysql databases by date created but am having some issues..I thought could  type `select host, user, db from mysql.user;`  with some other commands to get it to work...I've scoured the Internet and even found something similar on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work..is there a simple way of doing this?
I've tied the following   but it just gives me update time not date originally created

```
SELECT 
table_schema,
MAX(create_time) create_time,
MAX(update_time) update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
Group by TABLE_SCHEMA
Order by create_time desc
```

any hints greatly apreciated

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. First you want 'list my mysql databases', then you write 'select host, user, db from mysql.user', then you query 'information_schema.tables'. Are you interested in the databases, the tables (of all databases), the tables (of one database), or the table 'user'?

Comment: The date that the database was created isn't saved. You could use `MIN(create_time)` of all the tables as an approximation for when the database was created.

Answer (score 0):

Base on Barmar's suggestion:

```
   SELECT s.SCHEMA_NAME as database_name,
          MIN(t.CREATE_TIME) AS create_time
     FROM SCHEMATA s
LEFT JOIN TABLES t ON s.SCHEMA_NAME = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE s.SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema')
 GROUP BY s.SCHEMA_NAME
 ORDER BY create_time DESC
```

Note that a database with no tables will be listed with a 'NULL' create_time.